# How to exclude HTML from PHP and PHP file still able to link with the HTML file?

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller

[View table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHPGk.png)<-- this is my example. And code is provided too. I need to separate HTML from PHP, moving HTML to another file but my PHP code still be able to link with it. Is there any idea? I am trying to make something like View model controller.

````
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>View Records</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="form">
<p>
    <a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a> 
|   <a href="view.php">View Records</a> 
|   <a href="insert.php">Add Admin</a>
|   <a href="logout.php" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to Logout?');">Logout</a>

</p>

<table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><strong>ID</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Username</strong></th>
            <th><strong>User Password</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Full Name</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Edit</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Delete</strong></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</body>


<?php
$count=1;
$sel_query="Select * from admin ORDER BY id ASC;";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sel_query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>


<tr>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row["ID"]; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row["username"]; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row["user_pass"]; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row["fullname"]; ?></td>
    <td align="center">
        <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row["ID"];?>">Edit</a></td>
    <td align="center">
        <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row["ID"]; ?>"onclick="return confirm('Data cannot be retrieved after deleted. Are you sure to delete?');">Delete</a></td>


</tr>
<?php $count++; } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: MVC is a design pattern. Try implementing it then come back if you have any trouble.

Comment: You should check Laravel out, it's a PHP framework that uses MVC pattern.

Comment: There are a few options depending on what you want to achieve and how it will be used. Does the HTML need to be a user-editable template, for example?
My first thought would be to have your HTML have some placeholders for the data that will be filled in. I.e. there would be one <tr> defined, with some sort of recognisable markup for you to replace with values. Then in the PHP you read the HTML find the row template, loop over your data creating copies of the row, and then output.
btw: you have </body> where you should have <tbody>.

Comment: @xtempore Yes, the fields need to be filled by the user. Is the any way to move html thing to another file? But php function still be able to read from that file? *sorry for that <tbody>, my mistake.

Comment: How comfortable are you with OOP?  Although OOP is not a requirement, it certainly goes hand-in-hand with MVC.

Comment: If you are not ready to move up to an MVC I highly suggest at least using a template engine like [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very basic solution.

Make an HTML file as a template. E.g. "template.html". Use HTML comments as placeholders for the data. (I went with comments as it means the HTML remains compliant)
I've left out some of the non-relevant bits, so hopefully you get the idea:

```
<html>
...
<table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th><strong>ID</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Username</strong></th>
    <th><strong>User Password</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Full Name</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Edit</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Delete</strong></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<!--ROW-->
<tr>
    <td align="center"><!--ID--></td>
    <td align="center"><!--username--></td>
    <td align="center"><!--user_pass--></td>
    <td align="center"><!--fullname--></td>
    <td align="center">
        <a href="edit.php?id=<!--ID-->">Edit</a></td>
    <td align="center">
        <a href="delete.php?id=<!--ID-->"onclick="return confirm('Data cannot be retrieved after deleted. Are you sure to delete?');">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<!--ENDROW-->
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, in your PHP code, you read in the html, find the row template, and replace the fields as needed:

```
<?php
// Read the template
$html = file_get_contents('template.html');

// Find the row template
$regRowTemplate = '/<!--ROW-->(.*)<!--ENDROW-->/i';
preg_match($regRowTemplate, $html, $m);
$rowTemplate = $m[1];

// Start building our replacement rows
$htmlRows = '';

$count=1;
$sel_query="Select * from admin ORDER BY id ASC;";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sel_query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // Start with a fresh copy of the template
    $htmlRow = $rowTemplate;
    // Replace comment placeholders with values
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        $htmlRow .= str_replace('<!--' . $key . '-->', $value, $htmlRow);
    }
    // Append to our rows
    $htmlRows .= $htmlRow;
    $count++;
}
// Replace the row template with our expanded rows
$html = preg_replace(regRowTemplate, $htmlRows, $html);
// Do something with the html
```

Source untested, but should give you a good starting point. I kept it pretty raw. If I was doing this for real, I'd allow for the possibility of spaces in the comment placeholders by using a regular expression instead, but for now it's good enough.

Comment: hi, i have this error shown up :
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/test/view2php.php on line 14

as checked, is this $rowTemplate = $m[1]; <-- causing it.

Comment: I have make some edit, the error is gone but the page show blank....

Comment: The debugger is your friend. Step through the code. Makes sure that it is creating the rows. Most importantly: Read the last comment in my code "Do something with the html".
If your page is blank, it's probably because you haven't.

Comment: hi sir, that's the problem~ I am not so sure what to do with html, can you please provide more help on this? I'm quite new in this.

Comment: Is it I need to put something inside here? $regRowTemplate = '/<!--ROW-->(.*)<!--ENDROW-->/i';

Comment: As I already said, use the debugger to see what might be going wrong. But, you probably just need this at the end of your code.
echo $html;

Comment: hmm, i have echo this ```$regRowTemplate = '/<!--ROW-->(.*)<!--ENDROW-->/i';```

Comment: but it show weird thing like /(.*)/i  
so i guess is this problem.

Comment: i have made changes like this ```$html = file_get_contents('view2.php');

// Find the row template
$regRowTemplate = '/<!--ROW-->(.*)<!--ENDROW-->/i';
echo $regRowTemplate;
if (preg_match($regRowTemplate, $html, $m)) {
        return $rowTemplate = $m[1];
    } else {
        return null;
    }```

because the ```$rowTemplate = $m[1];```
cannot be put directly, it show error...

Comment: I tried to provide you with some basic code for this problem, but you seem to be way over your head. I am not going to do your job for you. If you are not happy with the sample code, I will delete this answer. It was never intended to be complete, just to give you a starting point. I expected you to have at least some knowledge of PHP and how to write and debug code.

Answer (score 1):

Separating the php and html is a good start, and helps you see the next step in converting to OOP and then MVC.

MVC at this point is too broad for a simple answer here, but I would recommend this as a first step as it has the underlying principles:

1. PHP is always at the top; never output anything until all your logic is finished
2. Load configuration
3. Work with user input and redirect if POST
4. Execute business logic
5. Exit PHP and output HTML.  Remember, PHP is essentially a templating language, might as well use it as such

Your code would then look something like this:

```
<?php

// load database connection, etc
$url = 'your url';

// deal with user input. Always use POST if data will be changed!
if($_POST['action'] == 'delete') {

  // delete from admin where id=?
  header('location: '.$url);
  die;
}

// end "controller" section
// begin "model" section

$sel_query="Select * from admin ORDER BY id ASC;";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sel_query);

// end "model" section
// begin "view" section. 
// Note, you could simply put the html in a separate file and just include it here. 

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>View Records</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="form">
<p>
    <a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a> 
|   <a href="view.php">View Records</a> 
|   <a href="insert.php">Add Admin</a>
|   <a href="logout.php" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to Logout?');">Logout</a>

</p>

<table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><strong>ID</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Username</strong></th>
            <th><strong>User Password</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Full Name</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Edit</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Delete</strong></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    </tbody>
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>

    <tr>
        <td align="center"><?= $row["ID"] ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?= $row["username"] ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?= $row["user_pass"] ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?= $row["fullname"] ?></td>
        <td align="center">
          <form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete" />
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $row["ID"] ?>" />
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that following this pattern is laying the groundwork for moving to mvc. But first, start working on your oop chops and move all the business logic into a model object.

After that, you can move the template to its own file, and have the model injected into the view, which lets the view have access to the info it needs, and then render the output.

Meanwhile, you'll need a router (all traffic is rerouted to index.php) and controller, and figure out which interpretation of MVC you will use ;)